# Clear a region so that views behind show through

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, wkwebview

Okay, so I have a base view that looks like this:

[image: base layer content]

And I have a view on top of it, with some subviews, that looks like this:

[image: both layers content]

Let's say those colourful squiggles represent my subviews in that overlay view.

But there are parts of my base layer I want to show through. If I had a rect like this one:

[image: rect that should clip overlay contents]

I would want it to look like this:

[image: overlay view contents clipped by rect]

I'm honestly at a bit of a loose end when it comes to implementing this. My first thought was to use `CGContextSetBlendMode(.Clear)`, but drawing is done *behind* subviews, not over them. I also can't just straight up render the contents of the subviews without adding them to my view, because when they're not clipped out, they still need to be interactive.

To throw a spanner in these works; that base layer is a WKWebView, and *it* still needs to be interactive, too.

I'm seriously stumped here. Any help?

Comment: So, what about a mask?

Comment: … I did not know that was a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a little difficulty understand what the difficulty is... You seem to be describing a mask. Maybe I'm wrong; I could be missing some further requirement. But with a mask I was easily able to attain this result:

[image]

That's a background with some words in it; in front of that, a clear view to host everything else; and the squiggles are subviews of the clear view. The clear view has a mask layer that cuts out the rectangular hole in the squiggles. Touch is unaffected by the clear view, since touches "fall through" a clear view; it's there just to host the mask (and the squiggles).

Comment: Yep, I had no idea that a mask existed. Not sure why I didn't search for that word considering a layer mask was exactly how I achieved that in Photoshop… chalk it up to a brainfart :P

Comment: More about masking layers in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch16.html#_shadows_borders_and_more And of course a view has a layer so that goes for views as well.